# Гарантирован ли порядок вычисления аргументов в вызове функции?

Tags: c++, c, функции

К примеру, у меня есть такой вызов функции:

```
std::unique_ptr tmp{new MyClassWithNameFunction};
foo(tmp->name(), std::move(tmp));
```

Гарантировано ли, что вызов метода `name()` будет происходить первым?

Comment: Здесь уже есть ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590020/344284

Comment: конечно не гарантировано

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Порядок вычисления аргументов в вызове функции — это пример неуточняемого поведения (англ. unspecified behavior). Такое поведение зависит от реализации (компилятора), но реализация свой выбор поведения документировать не должна.

Кстати говоря, порядок вычисления аргументов необязательно должен быть справа-налево или слева-направо. Более того, при вызове разных функций он может быть разным.

Answer (score 7):

Нет, не гарантирован.

Более того, большинство компиляторов наоборот будут вычислять аргументы справа налево.

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт.

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function
> designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every
> evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls)
> that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
> execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately
> sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.
>
> In other words, function executions do not ‘‘interleave’’ with each other.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> In the function call
>
> (*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
>
> the functions f1, f2, f3, and f4 may be called in any order. All side effects have to be completed before
> the function pointed to by pf[f1()] is called.

Перевод.

Существует точка последовательности после вычисления функции и фактических аргументов, но перед фактическим вызовом. Каждое вычисление в вызывающей функции (включая вызовы других функций), которая иначе специально не упорядочена до или после выполнения тела вызываемой функции, определяется неопределенным образом по отношению к выполнению вызываемой функции.

Другими словами, выполнение функций не «перемежается» друг с другом.

Пример

В вызове функции

```
(*pf[f1()]) (f2(), f3() + f4())
```

функции `f1`, `f2`, `f3` и `f4` могут вызываться в любом порядке. Все побочные эффекты должны быть завершены до вызова функции, на которую указывает `pf[f1()]`.