# Почему операции в потоке выполняются в обратном порядке?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, потоки-данных, static

Экспериментировал с шаблонами и наткнулся на неожиданный порядок выполнения операций в потоке.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
int A(T a) {
    static int t = static_cast<int>(a);
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    cout << A(5) << " " << A(6) << " " << A(7.2) << " " << A(7) << " " << A(2.8);

    return 0;
}
```

я ожидал получить

```
5 5 7 5 7
```

но получил

```
7 7 2 7 2
```

Очевидно что функции выполнялись не в том порядке, в котором я ожидал, но почему именно так?

Comment: странно. Я убрал static и все ок...

Comment: логично, что если убрать статик, то все будет ок

Comment: VC++ 2019 **с поддержкой С++17** дает именно то, что вы ожидали - 5 5 7 5 7... А чем пользовались вы? Скорее всего, чем-то, что не гарантирует вычисления этих `A()` для вывода в указанном порядке...

Comment: с++17 требует такого прямолинейного исполнения. А вот старые gcc делают наоборот.

Comment: вот тема прям раскрывается полностью и детально http://scrutator.me/post/2018/04/28/cpp17_lang_features_p3.aspx и даже есть объяснение, почему это было исправлено:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [О порядке вычисления выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590020/%d0%9e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Порядок вычисления аргументов функции не специфицирован. Например, для функции `void f(int i, int j)` при вызове с передачей в вызов других функций для порождения значений `i` и `j`, т.е.:

```
f(g(), k());
```

Нет гарантии того, что сначала будет вызвана `g()`, а только потом `k()`.

Ровно то же самое происходит в вашем случае. Порядок вывода задаётся `<<` как слева направо, однако сам вызов функций, которые порождают значения для вызова - неспецифицирован. При условии наличия состояния (статическая переменная внутри) функции это и приводит к такому, на первый взгляд, странному поведению.

Начиная с C++17 это исправлено (именно для `<<` и `>>`), и ваш код в нем будет работать правильно.

Comment: Да ну, если я вызову int a = f(1) + g(2), то мне никто не гарантирует что f() выполнится первым?

Comment: нет, никто не гарантирует. То, что у Вас вызывается f - просто так сложилось

Comment: @Антон вот пример: [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/usQepQ8PAtbVrDeQ) выполняется сначала `g`, потом `f`. А [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F4xFS6FmrVnPWIe4) наоборот.

Comment: начиная с с++17 определенные гарантии есть.

Answer (score 2):

Все из-за `static`. Как вы знаете статическая-переменная инициализируеться один раз. Второй раз - нет(остаеться предидущее значение). Компилятор создает 2 функции(одна с параметром `double` другая с параметром `int`).

То есть  `cout << A(5);` это мы первый раз вызываем `int-функцию` и статическая переменная инициализируеться `5`. Выводим на екран.

А второй раз вызвали - ту же самую функцию с интом-параметром! А статическая переменная уже была проиницализирована поэтому пропускаем присвоение нового числа и выводим старую пятерку!

```
cout << " " << A(7.2);
```

Вот это совсем другая `double-функция` и мы даем значение `7`. И тд.

С потоком выполнения все ОК

Comment: Если Вы внимательно прочитаете вопрос, то увидите ,что как раз 5 у автора и не вывелось на экран.

Comment: Элементы потока вычислялись справа налево. Самай правый (с плавающий точкой) инициализировал свою статическую переменную двойкой, следующий был целого типа и инициализоровал свой статик семеркой. Остальный возвращали соответственно уже только двойки (для элементов плавающего типа) и семерки