# что значит конструкция в выводе c++?

Tags: c++

Имеется следующий код на c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class my_stack
{
    static const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

    int stack[MAX_SIZE];
    int size;

public:
    void push(int a)
    {
        stack[size++] = a;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        return stack[--size];
    }
    my_stack()
    {
        size = 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_stack st;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        st.push(i);
    }
    std::cout << st.pop() << (st.pop(), st.push(6), st.pop()) << st.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять, что делает конструкция (,,) в строке:

```
std::cout << st.pop() << (st.pop(), st.push(6), st.pop()) << st.pop();
```

Результат работы программы:

```
236
```

Comment: Оператор запятая ([comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)).

Answer (score 5):

`A, B` равно просто `B`. Но `A` вычисляется перед `B`, и результат `A` отбрасывается.

`A, B, C` - аналогично. Результат равен `C`, но сначала вычисляется `A`, затем `B`, затем `C`.

Поэтому `std::cout << st.pop() << (st.pop(), st.push(6), st.pop()) << st.pop();` эквивалентно

```
std::cout << st.pop();
st.pop();
st.push(6);
std::cout << st.pop() << st.pop();
```

Comment: Не понимаю, почему вывод программы - 236, разве не 462? Где я ошибся? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StackProger так 462 и будет. а откуда вы вывод 236 взяли?

Comment: @StackProger, порядок вычисления слева направо операндов оператора сдвига (`<<`) гарантируется только с C++17. В более ранних версиях стандарта компилятор мог вычислять операнды в ином порядке. (см. [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/GTr3Ksb4M), [О порядке вычисления выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590020)).